# azure-storage-python - Exception handling with create_blob_from_path

Tags: python, azure

If for some reason the create_blob_from_path method runs into issues, what would be the proper way to handle the exception? As in, when you are writing your 'except' block, it would be except ??what?? as e: ? I want to be able to handle that exception when a blob upload fails so it can email me via sendmail so I know a backup that is attempting to be offloaded to Azure storage has failed.

Thank you!

Comment: Well, in Python, you don't make up your own exception names. I want to know the exception names for the azure-storage-python module. Also, that reply wasn't helpful or contributing anything.

Comment: so, i guess you cant google after all? https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python

Answer (score 1):

I looked for & searched some exception names on the source codes of Azure Python Storage SDK, there are not any exceptions defined about failure of uploading blob. However, per my experience, Azure Storage SDK for Python wrapped REST APIs of Storage Services via the python package `requests` to do related operations. So any failure will cause the `requests` exceptions, you can try to catch the `requests` root exception [`requests.exceptions.RequestException`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#errors-and-exceptions) as below to do the next action like `sendmail`.

```
import requests

try:
    blobservice.create_blob_from_path(container_name, blob_name, file_path)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
    sendmain(...)
```